# What could cause a perl cgi script to incorrectly interpret posted form data as UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi

I'm researching an error that has caused a Perl CGI script to write incorrect values to the database.

This perl script receives data from another system (not a browser) which definitely uses ISO-8859-1 encoding. The incorrect data, as it is written to the database, looks like this:

```
Gro�Gr�nF�rbung�sterreich
```

when it should be

```
GroßGrünFärbungÖsterreich
```

I found out that I can create such a wrong database entry by modifying the script to use `decode('utf8', $xyz)` instead of `$xyz`. So my question is: Are there any influences, e.g. HTTP headers, environment variables, config files etc. that could cause the perl CGI module to do this `decode` implicitely?

Original source code:

```
my $ack = new CGI;
my $xyz = $ack->param( 'xyz' );
```

in some cases apparently behaves like:

```
use Encode qw(decode encode);
my $ack = new CGI;
my $xyz = decode('utf8',$ack->param( 'xyz' ));
```

Comment: You should be happy there is no [captial sz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E) `ẞ` in there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should handle all data coming from outside the perl program itself as raw data bytes (octets). If you then explicitely `decode` it with your assumed encoding, process it in perl (in its native format) and `encode` it with the encoding you wish for to put it outside your program (like in your case into the database), you are on the safe side. Everything else could go wrong, like you can see.

When using handles (like files or sockets), you can do this by using the PerlIO layer, so you don't have to explicitely use decode/encode.

Comment: As much as I agree, for now I would be happy to find the exact circumstances when things go wrong.

Comment: Have you considered that the 'corruption' happens on the part from perl to the database? What's your DB encoding, what are you using for writing to it etc. ... If the input is definitely in iso-8859-1, is your DB encoding too? Especially the '-X' part at the end is sometimes the culprit, and this could have nothing to do with utf8. Just a thought...

Comment: ... and of course I'm preaching water and drink wine on the side - I nearly never do what I suggested, if I don't have to. Shame on me.

Comment: I've considered the possibility of the corruption happening in the db layer too, but if that was the reason, it would probably happen all the time.

Comment: Hm, maybe it's an operation in your data processing, where you mix the input with utf8-enabled strings (depending on the operation not always happening) - upgrading the resulting string to one with utf8-flag enabled. If your db writing routine is going by this flag to decide on its behavior, this could explain it. But at this point its just guess work, sorry.